# Yearly timer doesn't work

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer, ejb, scheduled-tasks

I'm using EJB 3.1.
In the following code I'm trying to create a yearly repetitive timer:

```
        ScheduleExpression scheduleExpression = new ScheduleExpression();
        Date now = new Date();
        scheduleExpression.start(now);     
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(now);
        scheduleExpression.minute(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        scheduleExpression.hour(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        scheduleExpression.dayOfMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        scheduleExpression.month(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
```

But it doesn't work, actually the behavior is quite random (in some repetition works and in another it doesn't).

The estrange thing is that I also have monthly repetition (see following code) and it is working.

```
    ScheduleExpression scheduleExpression = new ScheduleExpression();
    Date now = new Date();
    scheduleExpression.start(now);     
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(now);
    scheduleExpression.minute(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    scheduleExpression.hour(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    scheduleExpression.dayOfMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Any idea?

Comment: How do you *test* this: Waiting one year? I would never do that (such long periods), because you have to be very careful that the schedule is stored/restored after deployments, AS upgrades, HW upgrades whatever.

Comment: @Beryllium: changing wall time is one way.

Comment: @Beryllium: For testing this a have the application running in a virtual machine, just changing the date I can test it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Gregorian calendar implementation in Java months are zero-based, as told for example in javadocs of [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

> The first month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is
>   JANUARY which is 0; the last depends on the number of months in a
>   year.

Month in [ScheduleExpression](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/ScheduleExpression.html) is one-based:

> month : one or more months within a year
>
> Allowable values :
>
> - [1,12]
> - {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", Dec"}

Consequently code below constructs ScheduleExpression were month is one month in past (or in the case of January value 0 is invalid argument, but behavior in case of invalid seems not be strictly specified).

```
Date now = new Date();
...
scheduleExpression.dayOfMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Comment: Thank your, I will check if the strange behavior is because of this difference.

Comment: This was one of the problems, another one was that I was creating the timer in the past (for some seconds) and then it was not triggered. Thank you.